# Finding the absolute maximum of a 3 variable function

Tags: calculus, 3d

How do I approach finding the maximum for an $f(x,y,z)$?

$f(x,y,z)$= $6.365+7335000y-24450xy-0.5* \sqrt {10614564y^4+2391210000x^2y^2-1434726000000xy^2+31858027.2zy^2+215208923890984y^2+23904276.64z^2-1244994xy+373498200y-19947.936z+166.2145}$

I need to calculate the maximum value of the function for both of these seperately.

The locus is the cylinder $0<=x<=a$,   $\:y^2+z^2<=  b$ where $a,b$ are parameters.

**Context**: This is an expression for the principal stresses in a cylindrical beam, in a project I was working. I wish to find the maximum value of stress, and the element in which it occurs. Also, I have Finite Element Analysis results to compare with. **a=0.3**  **b=0.025**.

Here is the relevant MATLAB code

```
    clear all
syms x;
syms y;
syms z;
syms rho;

A=[(12.73+(1467-4.89*x)*y*10000)-rho  2444.6*z-1.02+1629*y^2  2444.6*y; 2444.6*z-1.02+1629*y^2  0-rho  0; 2444.6*y  0  0-rho  ];

eqn = det(A)==0

roots = solve(eqn, rho)


r1=roots(1)
r2=roots(2)
r3=roots(3)
```

Comment: Explicit function $f(x,y,z)$ is also needed.

Comment: The question may need some update for better understanding but it really sounds to me like you didn't notice that you have a [Lagrange's Multipliers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lagrange_multiplier) problems in hand.

Comment: @Mefitico yes, out of my depth here

Comment: Are you able to provide a factored version of the radical? Something like $\sqrt{(ax^2+by^2)^2+(cz-dx)^2}$? Where does the expression for $f$ come from?

Comment: @Mefitico from taking the determinant of the matrix in the code, equating it to zero, and solving for rho.

Comment: Then where did the matrix $A$ came from? But actually, it seems like you need to find the maximum value of the largest eigenvalue of $A$, under the constraint that  $(x,y,z)\in C$ (C is the cylinder). That would be a much clearer problem statement.

Comment: @Mefitico I'm not sure. Will have to look up my maths books

Comment: @Mefitico [http://www.informit.com/articles/article.aspx?p=1729271&seqNum=13 ][This] is where A comes from